# "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]" When Trying to Insert [PHP 8.0]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

So my code was working perfectly fine, until I tried to insert to the database..
my DB.php (The problem seems to be here, I checked all the other files and nothing is causing any problems, the function I used was the Insert function and I got an error on line 37:

```
<?php
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_result,
        $_count = 0;
    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db') . '', Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function query($sql, $params = array())
    {
        $this->_error = false;
        if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if (count($params)) {
                foreach ($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if ($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function action($action, $table, $where = array())
    {
        if (count($where) == 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
            $field = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value = $where[2];
            if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if ($this->query($sql, array($value))) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function get($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function delete($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function error()
    {
        return $this->_error;
    }
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->_count;
    }
    public function insert($table, $fields = array())
    {
        if (count($fields)) {
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $field){
                $values .= "?";
                if($x < count($fields)){
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`,`', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";
            echo $sql;
            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){  //where my error occurred
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

(The data's inserted to the table but that error seems crucial and I didn't find anything about it anywhere)
I watched a tutorial on YouTube and the problem occurred here- https://youtu.be/zvXgsouIzVg?t=5258

(The full error):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in D:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php:37 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php(37): PDOStatement->fetchAll(5) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php(93): DB->query('INSERT INTO use...', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(4): DB->insert('users', Array) #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php on line 37
```

Thanks in advance, that would help me a lot!

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` show, also if you can include the full error text in your question it may include more information about what is failing.

Comment: it shows:
INSERT INTO users (`username`,`password`,`salt`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
And I edited the question so the full error is there

Comment: I think the problem is that as you are doing an INSERT, calling `fetchAll` makes no sense.  You would need to work out what sort of statement this is and either not call `fetchAll` or work out how to cope with this error.

Comment: Ok.. but what can I call it instead... (I'm a newbie on PHP)

Comment: You can't create one general `query` method, because not all queries are executed equally. Some return a result set and some do not. Your method behaviour should account for that.